# How do I programmatically disable Hazelcast client's logging?

Tags: hazelcast

I used to use `networkConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "none")` in cluster's network configuration, but I can't see any logging-related configuration methods in any of `ClientConfig` and `ClientNetworkConfig`. Please help to save my server's log files.

Hazelcast version: 3.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do exactly the same thing on the ClientConfig using the ClientConfig.setProperty. Personally I never use it, I prefer to use the commandline option (-Dhazelcast.logging.type=blabla) because this give more predictable logging behavior.

Comment: Odd as it may seem, but there is no `ClientConfig.setProperty` for god only knows what reasons. Looks like dev team just forgot to add it to the interface.

Comment: ClientConfig cfg = new ClientConfig()

Comment: My bad. It is added in 3.3 (which will be released in a few days).

Comment: Ok, I consider the last comment as solution))

Comment: `clientConfig.setProperty("hazelcast.logging.type", "none")` doesn't have any effect, you need to set it as system property

Answer (score 1):

I use Hazelcast with the default JDK logger.
This works for me to save my server's log files:

```
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
    logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```